# How to plot a relationship between variables matblab

Tags: matlab, graph

I have 2 values and would like to plot the relationship against a constraint

val 1

2

val 2

0.2500

where the x axis will refer to val 1 with the y axis refering to val 2

the idea is to show the relationship between x and y such that if x increases so does y ( a diaganol line)

i would also like to place a constraint of 1 (a line across the y axis illustrating a cut of point)

how would i illustrate this in matlab.

thanks

Comment: It would be good to see a bit of code with the ideas that you have already tried.

Comment: online sources state the code is plot(x,y) with x refering to val1 and y val 2 which dosnt work in my case

Comment: Why does plot(x,y) fails? It works just fine. Do you need interpolation?

Comment: Hi i do not understand why it fails but i simply have 2 variables with two numerical values i use the plot command and an empty graph appears.

Comment: What exactly do you expect to see when using `plot(val1,val2)`? I am not sure if I understand the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Edited. I also copied part about constraint from @fpe answer.
If row is sorted, it will work fine.

```
row = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
col = [1, 4, 9, 7, 2, 4];
constr = ones(size(row));
subplot(2,1,1); plot(row, col, 'o', row, col, row, constr);
borders = size(row);
new_row = row(borders(1)):0.25:row(borders(2));
new_col = spline(row, col, new_row);
subplot(2,1,2); plot(row, col, 'o', new_row, new_col, row, constr);
```

[image]

First pic is just from data, second pic created with spline.

Comment: hi thanks just wondering what do the 2 lines above the plot command do?

Comment: They are for creating a spline - function that can describe relationship between arrays not like piecewise function but the way analytical function would make it. I will add a pics to make it clear.
Sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example

```
x = 0:.0001:1;
y = 2*x;
constr = ones(size(y));
plot(x,y,'r','LineWidth',1.0), hold on,  plot(x,constr,'g','LineWidth',1.0), hold off, grid on;
```

The resulting plor follows:

[image]
**EDIT**

Have you tried with

```
plot(val1,val2,'-or')
stem(val1,val2)
```

too? I can visualize the point (val1,val2). Otherwise I am missing your question.

Comment: i think my issue was that i am trying to plot x with a matrix format of 2x1 by a single value